# How to run tests from renamed or not default folder?

Tags: php, yii2, automated-tests, integration-testing, codeception

*Yii2*  has tests folder structure:

```
- tests
  - _data/
  - _output/
  - _support/
  - acceptance/
  - functional/
  - unit/
  - _bootstrap.php
  - acceptance.suite.yml.example
  - functional.suite.yml
  - unit.suite.yml
```

Я set up tests via *PhpStorm* and *Codeception*. It works fine. Test can be launched successfully. But I want to do integrational tests. I made a `integrational` folder, wrote test, clicked "Run" and this test didn't run. I mean, codeception didn't even go into the folder.

If I rename `unit` folder into `unit2` or `functional` into `functional2`, then I get thr error:

> Running with seed:
>
> In Bootstrap.php line 31:
> Bootstrap file /var/www/myproject/tests/functional/_bootstrap.php can't be
> loaded

I thought that paths is hardcoded. But `Bootstrap.php` has the lines:

```
public function loadBootstrap(SuiteEvent $e)
{
    $settings = $e->getSettings();
    //....
    
    $bootstrap = $settings['path'] . $settings['bootstrap'];
    if (!is_file($bootstrap)) {
        throw new ConfigurationException("Bootstrap file $bootstrap can't be loaded");
    }

    require_once $bootstrap;
}
```

---

Anyway. How do I configure settings (and where) to be available to run tests from the custom named folder? How to run integrational tests from integrational folder for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer wrote Dmitriy Eliseev from https://yiiframework.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?p=273945#p273945

It's so simple.

The suites are picked up from `*.suite.yml` files.

So,in addition to `unit.suite.yml` and `functional.suite.yml` inside `tests` folder you should add an `integrational.suite.yml` file with settings. In this case tests from `integrational` folder will be work as well.

Comment: You can use `codecept generate:suite integrational` command to generate all necessary files.